typeorm 0.3.7 vs typeorm 0.3.20 - possible issue loading relationships
I have the following query:
  async findOneByAddress(address: Address): Promise<Account | null> {
    const where: FindOptionsWhere<Account> = {
      account: {
        subacct: { 
          address: Equal(address.toString())
        },
      },
    };

    return await this.accountsRepository.findOne({ 
      where, 
      ['user', 'account', 'account.subacct'],
    });
  }


In typeorm 0.3.7, it loads all 5 utxoAccountAddresses. In typeorm 0.3.20, it only loads the matching one. This behavior is true for both find and query builder queries.
Is there a new option somewhere that will allow me to use the old relationship builder in the new version of typeorm?
Is this a bug?

Not that I know of, but here is a possible work around for the issue where TypeORM 0.3.20 loads only the matching utxoAccountAddress instead of all associated ones, you can perform a two-step process. First, find the Account based on the utxoAccountAddress that matches the given address. Then, manually load all utxoAccountAddresses associated with the utxoAccount of the found Account. This approach requires an extra step but ensures you get all utxoAccountAddresses related to the Account.
Hope this helps. Cheers.
 async findOneByUtxoAddress(address: CryptoAddress): Promise<Account | null> {
  // Step 1: Find the Account with the matching utxoAccountAddress
  const account = await this.accountsRepository.findOne({
    where: {
      utxoAccount: {
        utxoAccountAddresses: { address: Equal(address.toString()) },
      },
    },
    relations: {
      utxoAccount: true, // Make sure to load the utxoAccount relationship
    },
  });

  if (!account) {
    return null; // Return null if no account was found
  }

  // Step 2: Explicitly load all utxoAccountAddresses for the utxoAccount of the found Account
  // Assuming `utxoAccountId` is accessible or you have a similar identifier to use
  const utxoAccountId = account.utxoAccount.id; // Adjust according to your actual data structure
  const utxoAccountAddresses = await this.utxoAccountAddressRepository.find({
    where: {
      utxoAccount: { id: utxoAccountId },
    },
  });

  // Manually set the utxoAccountAddresses to the account.utxoAccount.utxoAccountAddresses
  account.utxoAccount.utxoAccountAddresses = utxoAccountAddresses;

  return account;
}


Gonna wait a bit and see if there's a more official answer. If not, I'll mark yours as it. Thanks for taking the time!
